# Menu "flashes" in Rails 7 and Turbo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I am trying to build a very simple menu with submenus using Rails 7, Bootstrap 5 and Jquery.

HTML:

```
   <div>
    <button class="toggle-submenu">Sales</button>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/sales/recent">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sales">All</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="toggle-submenu">Products</button>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/products">All</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu-open {
  height: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-submenu', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.submenu').toggleClass('submenu-open');
    $('.submenu').not($(this).parent().find('.submenu')).removeClass('submenu-open');
});
```

So all this does is when clicking a button, adding the "submenu-open" class to it's closest "submenu" div and removing it from all others.

But what happens is that when clicking on one a link inside the submenu it flashes the other submenu until the server responses (for testing I added a sleep 3 to my controller, and then the "flash" lasted for 3 seconds). See the GIF below:

[image]

In the GIF I click on the all link inside products and for a short moment the sales submenu opens.

When disabling turbo the issue disappears. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try running this outside of Rails. Just to make sure it is/or isn't and issue with Turbo itself?

Comment: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#understanding-caching

Answer (score 1):

You're not [preventing the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and not [preventing the event from propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). It would actually be more suprising if the Turbo handler didn't fire and replace the page.

This is something you always have to do when attaching event handlers to elements with default behavior such as links, buttons and forms.

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-submenu', function(event) {
  let active =  $(this).parent().find('.submenu');
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropogation();
  active.toggleClass('submenu-open'); 
  $('.submenu').not(active).removeClass('submenu-open');
});
```

With jQuery you can also do both by returning false from the event handler.

Comment: I also don't really understand how you think this should work. You need to put a lot more thought into it if you want this menu to actually load the pages and persist its state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I broke the example down to the basics that show the problem. To make the menu persistent is, of course, another step.